# Too many queries? Game server

Tags: mysql

I'm coding a game server (a SAMP game server to be specific) and I'm looking to change the way the players' data is saved.

At the moment, data is loaded from MySQL into variables in the server. For example, a player's money gets loaded into a per-player variable called "Money" (looks a little like: DATA[playerid][Money]).

If a player kills another player, their variable DATA[playerid][Kills] gets incremented. Then, every few minutes, and when the player disconnects from the server (i.e they close the game, the game crashes, etc.), a MySQL update query runs and just stores everything from their variables into their row in the "players" table in the database.

However, if the server crashes, data could be lost, even if it is just a few minute's worth (players can earn a decent amount of money in a few minutes), so I'm thinking of changing it so that rather than incrementing a variable, it just increments the particular field in the database. For example, if a player earns $100, an update query just adds 100 to the money field in their row in the db.

Obviously this means that if a lot of players are fighting, lots of kills, deaths, money and score points will be earnt, which means lots of queries are being sent to the MySQL server. Will this cause problems, like slowing anything down or causing crashes? Is it worth it to ensure no data is lost? I heard from someone that Twitter used to send thousands of queries to one MySQL server.

I also log chat messages, so every time a player sends a chat message, a query is sent. Would this cause problems if say there were 2-3 messages per second?

Comment: If it crashes, get a bigger DB server!  A better way here is probably to put the data into an in memory cache like Redis, then to periodically write from Redis into MySQL.

Comment: Basically every onlinegame looses data when the server crashes. You don't have to be the one exception (assuming it's not real money). Or does your server crashes often that this should be a concern? It depends on your server specs if it will cause problems. And there are then ways to tackle that. But why don't you just test your server (and potential tackle ways) by changing your interval from "every few minutes" over some steps downto "every second" (you might then want to add a change-marker I guess). You could even adjust this to the current player count (more load, higher interval).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need an in between step: Play-> Partial Save -> Batch Save in DB.
Maybe it's a little of an overkill for your application, but have you tried thinking about "logging" your partial informations via data broker, [like Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/)? If you had a producer (which writes the data), the kafka server will automatically tell the consumer (which reads the data) where it was before crashing.
[Or Redis](http://redis.io/), as suggested in the comments, although it may be even more an overkill.